# How do I enable Blocked Connection Notifications extension in RabbitMQ

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq

I am trying to use the `blocked` and `unblocked` channel events using Nodejs module `amqplib` on RabbitMQ. My understanding is RabbitMQ will send a connection blocked command to the producers if the system resources have reached an "alarm" state. My intention is to utilize this to determine if the producer should proceed in creating a job, or to respond to with a "try again later".

amqplib docs: http://www.squaremobius.net/amqp.node/channel_api.html#model_events

Here are the versions of software I am using:

- RabbitMQ 3.6.6, Erlang R16B03
- NodeJS 6.9.2
- amqplib ^0.5.1 (node module)
- Ubuntu 14.04

### Things I have tried

My nodejs code:

```
var amqp = require('amqplib');
amqp.connect('amqp://localhost').then((connection) => {
    return connection.createChannel();
}).then((channel) => {
    channel.on('blocked', (reason) => {
        console.log(`Channel is blocked for ${reason}`);
    });
    channel.on('unblocked', () => {
        console.log('Channel has been unblocked.');
    });

    return channel.assertQueue('myQueue', {
        durable : true,
        // This doesn't seem to do anything
        arguments : {
            "connection.blocked" : true
        }
    }).then(() => {
        channel.sendToQueue('myQueue', new Buffer('some message'), {
            persistent : true
        });
    });
});
```

I understand that this particular feature is an extension to the AMQP protocol and needs to be enabled/declared. I'm not very familiar with the erlang config syntax. Using an example config, I built a config that looks something like:

```
[{rabbit, [
    {"server-properties", [
        {"compatibilities", {
            { "connection.blocked", true }
        }}
]}
```

As per the docs here: https://www.rabbitmq.com/consumer-cancel.html#capabilities

> "To receive these notifications, the client must present a
>   capabilities table in its client-properties in which there is a key
>   connection.blocked and a boolean value true. See the capabilities
>   section for further details on this. Our supported clients indicate
>   this capability by default and provide a way to register handlers for
>   the connection.blocked and connection.unblocked methods."

And then restarted the server using `service rabbitmq-server restart`.

This does not crash the server, but the events do not fire either. I'm expecting that the connection should become block in the event that system resources are low. The RabbitMQ docs has a link for more info on `Capabilities` but the link is dead, and I'm not sure what else to try.

Answer (score 1):

`blocked` and `unblocked` are on `connection` not on `channel`.

In your example: `connection.on('blocked', console.log)` and `connection.on('unblocked', () => console.log('unblocked'))`.

To test it just run: `rabbitmqctl set_vm_memory_high_watermark 0.000001` and send a new message to your queue.

`compatibilities` are enabled by default, and `amqplib` informs server about `connection.blocked`. Nothing should be done here.

Comment: I see, their documentation is a little confusing since its mixed in with the Channel stuff. I'll try this later tonight and let you know how it turns out.